# Problem with serial communication between Python and a Totalstation (laser distance measurement)

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I am working on a python script (Python 3.11.3 on windows 11) that through serial communication with a laser distance/angle finder (a Totalstation South NTS-362R4L), can write and activate the laser distance/angles measurement whereafter the laser should return measurements for the Python script to read.

Procedures should be:

- PC send "C 067 ETX" to laser
- Within 0.05 seconds the laser should respond "ACK 006 ETX" whereafter it should send the measurement

I have been succesfull in activating the laser however the responses are not understandable and varies from nothing to sometimes and always in different ways (despite measureing the same spot).

```
# Script to read and write from Lynx LaserLynx (NTS-362LR4)

import serial
import time

# Settings
port = 'COM6'
baud_rate = 9600
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
stop_bits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
data_bits = serial.EIGHTBITS
timeout = 1

# Note from Laserlynx (Totalstation: South NTS-363R4L) settings
# Protocol: Ack/Nak
# Baud: 9600 b/s
# Parity: 8/NON

# Open serial port with settings
ser = serial.Serial(
    port=port,
    baudrate=baud_rate,
    parity=parity,
    stopbits=stop_bits,
    bytesize=data_bits,
    timeout=timeout
)

# Check to see if serial port is open
if ser.is_open:
    print("Serial port "+port+" is open")
else:
    print("Serial port "+port+" is closed")
print(" ")    

# APPROACH
# Activate Laser: C 067 ETX CRLF
# 43H 30H 36H 37H 03H 0DH 0AH
# 43303637030D0A
# \x43\x30\x36\x37\x03\x0D\x0A

# Effective reception: ACK 006 ETX CRLF
# 06H 30H 30H 36H 03H 0DH 0AH
# 06303036030D0A
# \x06\x30\x30\x36\x03\x0D\x0A

# Invalid reception: NAK 021 ETX CRLF
# 14H 30H 32H 31H 03H 0DH 0AH
# 14303231030D0A
# \x14\x30\x32\x31\x03\x0D\x0A

# ASCII HEX SYMBOL translation
# https://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm


# HEX commands
# Class 1
hex_command  = '43303637030D0A' # Activate Laser "C"

# Class 2
hex_success  = '06303036030D0A' # Succesfull response
hex_failure  = '14303231030D0A' # Ineffective response

# Attempts to send commands
noofattempts = 5

# Function to convert hexadecimal string to bytes
def hex_to_bytes(hex_string):
    return bytes.fromhex(hex_string)

# Read responses function
def read_responses(duration):
    end_time = time.time() + duration
    responses = []
    while time.time() < end_time:
        if ser.in_waiting > 0:
            # Read undtil LF and 2028 bytes
            #response = ser.read_until('LF',2048)
            
            # Read entire line
            response = ser.readline()
            
            # Read from buffer
            #response = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
            
            # Optional decoding - only if valid chaaracters            
            #.decode('utf-8').rstrip()
            
            responses.append(response)
            
    return responses
    
    
# Variable to log counting
attempts = 0


# Send command and read response
while attempts < noofattempts:

    # WRITING
    try:
        ser.write(hex_to_bytes(hex_command))
        
    except serial.SerialException:
        print("Error: serial.SerialException")
        
    except serial.SerialTimeoutException:
        print("Error: serial.SerialTimeoutException")
    
    print(str(attempts) + '.')
    print('Sent:', hex_command)
    print('Sent:', hex_to_bytes(hex_command))


    # Added delay to receive data from the serial ports input buffer
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
    # READING FOR 1 SECONDS
    # LaserLynx must respond within 50ms
    responses = read_responses(1)
    
    # Evaluate response
    if responses == '\x06' or responses == b'\x06' or responses == b'\x06\x30\x30\x36\x03':
    
        # Positive outcome
        print('ACK RECEIVED:', responses)
        # As ACK is received LaserLynx will then send the measurement
        # Read and print out measurement
        responses = read_responses(1)        
        print(responses)
        
        ser.write(hex_to_bytes(hex_success))
        print('Sent success:', hex_success)              
        break

    else:
    
        # No outcome
        print('RECEIVED:', responses)
        #ser.write(hex_to_bytes(hex_failure))
        #print('Sent:', hex_failure) 
        #print('Sent:', hex_to_bytes(hex_failure)) 
        
        attempts += 1
    
    ser.flush()    
    print(" ")
  
# Close serial port
ser.close()
```

The manual states the following procedure:
Manual states:
Process of starting and receiving measurement data in the mode of single measurement and repeated measurement:

1. PC sends Class 1 instruction to instrument(Command“C”)
2. Instrument checks BBC (Block Check Code) of command "C", if the received instruction is right, instrument will send admitting signal "ACK" to computer in 0.05s. Otherwise instrument will not send answering signal to computer.
3. If it doesn't receive the admitting signal "ACK" from instrument in 0.05s, computer must send command "C" again.
4. Step 3) can be repeated 10 times at most, and if it is more than 10 times, computer will interrupt communication and display error information.
5. When instrument receives the command "C", it starts to measure; then send data after measurement.
6. When it receives the data correctly and checks BBC, computer must send "ACK" to instrumentin 0.3s. And communication finishes when instrument receives "ACK".
7. If there is communication error with the received data, computer can't send "ACK". Then, instrument will send the same data to computer again.
8. Step 7) can be repeated 10 times at most, and if it is more than 10 times, computer will interrupt communication and display errorinformation.

Running the above code will deliver this reponse:
C:\PythonLaser>py laser3.py
Serial port COM6 is open

0.
Sent: 43303637030D0A
Sent: b'C067\x03\r\n'
RECEIVED: []

1.
Sent: 43303637030D0A
Sent: b'C067\x03\r\n'
RECEIVED: [b'5n\xf7\xf7\xa6[\xfb']

2.
Sent: 43303637030D0A
Sent: b'C067\x03\r\n'
RECEIVED: []

3.
Sent: 43303637030D0A
Sent: b'C067\x03\r\n'
RECEIVED: []

4.
Sent: 43303637030D0A
Sent: b'C067\x03\r\n'
RECEIVED: []

The expected response from the laser should be:

- ?+00002157m2675319+0320026d+00002156*00+00+00062EXT(CRLF)
- 3F 2B 30 30 30 30 32 31 35 37 6D...........
- \x3F\x2B..........

In the above example I got this response - that however varies alot and does not make any sense:

- b'5n\xf7\xf7\xa6[\xfb'

My problem shooting so far has been on:

1. The specific "command"
   The laser seems quite flexible activating the laser on only fragments of the manuals required command.
2. The reading delay and period
   I apparantly need to use a minimum of 0.5 seconds to get data from the laser.
   The manual states that 0.05 seconds is the limit wherein the laser should respond if command was good.
3. The optional settings for the laserlynx serial connection

   - Using 9600b/8/NON seems most stable
   - I havent been able to translate Ack/Nak to Python requirements?
   - The laser can also be set to "one way" rather than Ack/Nak
4. Flow control

   - I havent been able to fully understand flow control - if this is relevant in the trouble shooting?